Equations to rotate and position triangles around a regular polygon?
What equations can one use to orient and layout the triangles on any regular pentagon from 3 to let's say 12 sides? Like this:

Here, we have 3 at side 1, 1 at side 3, and 2 at side 5. The triangles are pointing out away from the pentagon as well, and have (in theory) the same gap separating the triangles from the main polygon body.
How can you calculate the position and orientation of the triangles, given you know the triangle ideal circumscribing circle (i.e. "width" or "2*radius").

There can be let's say 1 to 10 triangles per side.
You tell it how many triangles you want on what side, and it gives you back the orientation and position of each triangle, to be laid out.

Any help would be appreciated. Even just explaining where I might learn about certain aspects of trigonometry / geometry to figure out a solution on my own.

Here is what ChatGPT says, but it is hard for me to mentally parse. Perhaps it is correct, or needs tweaking, but maybe it can serve as inspiration.

Follow-up/related code question.

One way is…

Obtain the polygon’s vertices (trivial if you express the coordinates in $\mathbf C$ instead of $\mathbf R^2$.  You can then convert.)
Calculate the parametric form of the equation for the line containing each edge, with $t=0$ at one vertex and $t=1$ at the other.
Rotate your triangles so their bases are parallel to an edge.

The rest should be straightforward.


The $n$th roots of unity are the vertices of the regular $n$-gon inscribed in the unit circle with one vertex at $(1,0)$. So their coordinates are $(\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{n}), \sin(\frac{2k\pi}{n}))$ for $0 \leq k < n$.



The line through $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ can be parameterized as $${((1-t)a+tc, (1-t)b+td)|t\in{\mathbf R}}.$$ (Check out what happens for $t=0,1$.)


2a. You can evenly space $\tau$ triangles by plugging in $t=\frac{k}{\tau+1}$ for $1\leq k\leq\tau$ in the parameterization, where $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are the appropriate successive $n$th roots of unity from step 1.

(You ought to be able to work out the rotation and translation of the triangles for yourself.)
